# create dictionary from lookup table

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a look up table that looks something like so (space separated with space at the beginning of line one to offset the values appropriately):

FileA.txt

```
 Match1 Match2 Match3
find1 20 30 40
find2 60 50 90
find3 70 80 40
```

I need be able to use a separate file to find the appropriate lookup value. For example here is FileB.txt:

```
find1    Match2
find3    Match1
```

And this is what I'd want my final output to look like:

```
find1    Match2    30
find3    Match1    70
```

However, I'm not sure how to import a lookup table into python. I'm assuming I'd have to use a dictionary. However, I'm not quite sure how to create a dictionary from a lookup table.

Comment: mind sharing your thoughts about your approach ?

Comment: I really have no idea where to even start. I'm not sure how to read the file into a dictionary

Comment: You can't read the file directly into a dictionary unless the file contains json. You will have to create a dictionary yourself with some logic.

Comment: could you explain me what need ? i cant understand, how is the find? in list?

Comment: There are two parts to this: 1. read a file and parse its values, 2. take those values and put them in some type of 2D container (typically a dictionary of dictionaries or a list of lists). Read about python file I/O in the docs and string operations such as `split()` to answer the first part of the question and experiment/search for the second. Return here and post your code if the whole thing blows up :)

Comment: @JDo will do. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could use regular expression for search

```
import re
filexd = open('file.txt', 'r')
data = filexd.readlines()
exp = re.compile(r'([0-9]{2})+') # compile expression for search, capture groups of two numbers
match = []
for x in data: # x is each line, for example 'find1 20 30 40'
    if exp.findall(x): # if group of 2 numbers or more exist
        match.append(exp.findall(x)) # add all found groups

print match
>>>[['20', '30', '40'], ['60', '50', '90'], ['70', '80', '40']]
print match[0]
>>>['20', '30', '40']
print match[0][2]
>>>40
```

Comment: Ah. I see what your doing. However, it's not appropriate for my use. The `find`'s and `Match`'s are specific strings that are used for matching.